# Custom ordering by calculation in Django

Tags: django, sorting

Any solutions for custom calculation sorting in Django? I want to create a view that shows the Top Posts in my Blog. The ranking will be calculated by Post's attributes. Let's just say I have 3 IntegerFields called x, y, and z, and the ranking calculation will be x * y / z.

Any ideas? I would like to do Top Post ever, and also other variations filtered by time such as last 24 hours, 7 days, 1 month, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`extra`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to retrieve extra calculated column(s) and sort by it:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(post_date__lt=#date#)
       .extra(select={'custom_order': "x*y/z"}).order_by('custom_order')
```

The problem with this approach is that you're writing sql so it is not always portable across databases (although, for the example you supplied, this problem is avoided because it's a simple calculation)

Otherwise, you can do the sorting with pure python:

```
sorted_models = sorted(MyModel.objects.filter(post_date__lt=#date#)
                , key=lambda my_model:my_model.x*my_model.y/my_model.z))
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I thought about sorting with pure Python, but I was afraid that that would mean a large SELECT would be done first, and then sorted by Python. I could be completely wrong of course.

Comment: Of course, doing the sort in the database is most of the time more efficient, but that would require writing `sql` statements (database-dependent). On the other hand, sorting with python ensures a database-independent working code all the time. It depends on each situation (data size, response time, multiple backends) to decide which one to choose.

Answer (score 0):

The extra() queryset method should allow you to do this.  See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

Comment: Update the docs  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Comment: Updated with the new link

Answer (score -1):

As you can't order querysets by methods and properties in django you have to do the sorting in python.

Consider turning your calculated field into a [property](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/18/django-tips-using-properties-models-and-managers/) on your model and then you can do this in your view:

```
sorted_posts = sorted(Post.objects.all(), key=lambda post: post.calculated_field )
```

Finally you can pass `sorted_posts` to your list-template.